# How current is the use of "but" to mean "except for"?

Tags: prepositions

I am  [aware](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286992/none-but-the-brave-deserves-the-fair-what-part-of-speech-is-but) [of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89897/more-grammatically-correct-anything-but-or-anything-except) the use of *but* to mean *except for*.

My question is: how current is this usage?

Is it appropriate to use it in contemporary documents that are not literature production? (for example: technical documents)

Comment: It's quite common, but it usually occurs only with universal quantifiers like the _all_ in the following sentence: _All of them are here but Jane and Hilda ~ All of them but Jane and Hilda are here._ You need the universal quantifier to use _but_ that way.

Comment: As Lawler says, it's quite common to hear "Everyone's here *but* Jane."  Somewhat less common but still idiomatic (though a little Britishy) is "We have all the ingredients *but for* one."

Comment: You hear it a lot in the South in the formulation: "It's all over but the shoutin'!" meaning a contest has been settled.

Comment: It's certainly more common than *save* in the same constructions.

Comment: The related (if not identical) 'had it not been' sense also exists – I would have been killed but for your warning. Probably fairly rare / literary in the UK nowadays. And the use after 'do' –  'He does nothing but lie around all day' – is, I'd say, pretty common.

Comment: "Anything but that", "anyone but him", "anywhere but there" etc. These are very common in the UK.

Comment: Thanks @JohnLawler! You also answered to the subsequent question, that is: which is the usual construct for this usage of "but".
A colleague of mine uses it very frequently, without using the quantifiers, and the resulting sentences sound a little odd. They are easy to understand if "except for" is used instead.

Comment: @JohnLawler can you make your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?